# How to handle bitwise operations with structs in Swift?

Tags: swift

In Obj-C, I like to do things like:

```
[MyUILib makePathForRectWithEdges:UIRectEdgeLeft|UIRectEdgeRight]
```

In which the argument is an NSInteger, which I later compare to UIRectEdge enum values to see which sides I want to include in the path:

```
if(edges & UIRectEdgeTop)
{
   // Draw Stuff
}
```

In Swift, Apple defines UIRectEdge as:

```
struct UIRectEdge : OptionSetType {
    init(rawValue rawValue: UInt)
    static var None: UIRectEdge { get }
    static var Top: UIRectEdge { get }
    static var Left: UIRectEdge { get }
    static var Bottom: UIRectEdge { get }
    static var Right: UIRectEdge { get }
    static var All: UIRectEdge { get }
}
```

I can still use `UIRectEdge.Top.rawValue` to get a UInt, but calling a function like: `makePathForRectWithEdges(UIRectEdge.Left.rawValue|UIRectEdge.Right.rawValue)` is ugly and hard to read compared to how I used to do it. Is there a better pattern for using flags, or is this just how it has to be in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of or-ing the raw value, you send a set to the functions:

```
MyUILib.makePathForRectWithEdges([.Left, .Right])
```

Hence the name `OptionSetType`. When you need to check if an option is included in the set:

```
if edges.contains(.Top) { ... }
```